# How to manually get number of updates as displayed on login to terminal

Tags: command-line, updates

I am wondering how, when on login to my terminal (Ubuntu 16) I see information like:

```
10 updates are available  
6 updates are security updates
```

Where is this information retrieved from?

How can I get the same information from command line manually?

If this is a script that is run, where is it?

Comment: The information is stored at /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available . See `man update-motd` The numbers are updated daily by a script, so more hours since that update means less accurate information.